# Different ways to use a function as template argument

Tags: c++, templates

I need to create a template function which calls an exchangeable "worker" function over and over again.

```
template<class F>
int exec(F f) {
    long long s = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<1000000; i++) {
        s += f(i); // many calls to f
    }
    return s;
}
```

Now I thought of different possibilities of defining the worker function:

1. Inline function

   ```
   inline int fooInline(int a) { return a + 1; }
   exec(fooInline);
   ```
2. Function with definition from other compilation unit

   ```
   int fooSrc(int a);
   exec(fooSrc);
   ```
3. Function object

   ```
   struct FooOp {
       int operator()(int a) { return a + 1; }
   };
   exec(FooOp());
   ```
4. `std::function` (e.g. bound to an inline function)

   ```
   std::function<int(int)> fooFnc = std::bind(&fooInline);
   exec(fooFnc);
   ```
5. Lambda

   ```
   auto fooLambda = [](int a) { return a + 1; };
   exec(fooLambda);
   ```
6. Temporary lambda

   ```
   exec([](int a) { return a + 1; });
   ```

What are the differences between theses methods? What would be the fastest way? Can I assume that `exec(fooInline)` will actually inline `fooInline`?

Comment: You measure and observe which one performs better in your concrete program.

Comment: Lambda's are just function objects, they are not magical. I.e. 3,5 and 6 are identical.

Comment: @MSalters: Are they also the same as 1?

Comment: No, but they are definitely similar. (i.e. implementation available for inlining. The `inline` keyword doesn't matter BTW)

Answer (score 0):

Within C++ there is no answer to your question which one would be the fastest. You can measure in your particular environment but then again you do not have any guarantees.

The guess would be that the compiler has the biggest chance to inline if it has easy access to the source of the worker function, so inline function or temporary lambda would be the best. But still a decent compiler might inline in all of the methods you listed.

Comment: The temporary lambda is exactly the same as the non-temporary lambda. Both are inline-able calls to `__UnnamedTypeXYZ::operator()`.